# Why Masstransit automatic create exchange name bus-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx

Tags: masstransit

I start using masstransit with rabbitmq in dotnetcore.
i study it behavior and noticed that it will create exchange and queue name
'bus-{computer name}-dotnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' automatically
i want to know why it create and what it do.
I view it in rabbitmq dashboard.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something like a Request/Response, then Response address will be this temporary bus address. Additionally you can connect consumers to this temporary endpoint as [described here](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html#connecting-to-an-existing-bus) in the documentation. Be aware that you can only .Send(...) to this endpoint. a .Publish(...) will never be able to deliver to the buses temporary endpoint.

Comment: Thank you maldworth it make me understand better